# How does container communicate with another via python when there is no port exposed?

Tags: docker

In example here- https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/

Flask:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
cache = redis.Redis(host='redis', port=6379)
```

Dockerfile:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM python:3.7-alpine
WORKDIR /code
ENV FLASK_APP=app.py
ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST=0.0.0.0
RUN apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev linux-headers
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
COPY . .
CMD ["flask", "run"]
```

Compose:

```
    version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    environment:
      FLASK_ENV: development
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
```

Web app runs in container  on 0.0.0.0 port 5000

Redis runs on separate container and default port 6389

The web app container is run by exposing port 5000:5000

I am trying to understand how does the web app container communicate with the redis container when there is no network specified. Or when the port 6389 of the other container is not exposed?

Comment: See also [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation.  "Expose" means almost nothing in modern Docker and it isn't required for inter-container communication.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no network information provided in the `docker-compose.yml` file, Docker will use a default subnet for the container (unless explicitly named, it will be called `${current_working_dir}_default}`.  Since the two containers are technically on the same subnet, it is possible for them to communicate with each other without exposing ports.  Using `EXPOSE` to expose ports is generally for allowing users the host machine to communicate with a container (i.e., opening the Flask app with a browser on your laptop).

In order for your Flask app to communicate with Redis, you may need to add a `hostname` descriptor to the `redis` service in your `docker-compose.yml` file.  Otherwise, the hostname for the `redis` service may just be some SHA hash, and it would make it hard for the Flask app to find it (unless you know and use the IP address to the `redis` service)

Comment: Ok so all the containers involved in the compose script will have their own default bridged network.

Comment: Correct -- when you do `docker-compose up`, you'll see `Creating network "<name_of_current_directory>_default" with the default driver`

Comment: Neither `hostname:` nor `container_name:` are usually required.  `hostname:` in particular only affects what a container thinks its own hostname is, and it has no effect on networking or how other containers might reach it.